# Jquery Mobile make problems with Image Slider bxSlider

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, bxslider

i need your help. I have the follwoing page http://mobile.mmkonzerte.de/ and on this page I use jQuery Mobile and as Slider bxSlider.
The page itself runs good. But when I jump from one page to the other the Slider show first for 1-2 seconds all pictures without css format.

Any idea why this happen?

Second if I click on the Browser back button the Slider will not show anymore and instead some bullets.

Any idea also on this case?

Thansk
Mark

Answer (score 0):

I think you should destroy the page slider in page's [pagebeforeshow](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/) event
and re-initialize it in page show event

here is the code for pagebeforeshow.

```
$('#page').on('pagebeforeshow', function() {
     sliderSelector.destroySlider();
     console.log("page before show.")
});
```

now in pageshow event initialize it like this

```
$('#page').on('pageshow', function() {  
     console.log("page is shown");
     //now you can initialize slider   
     sliderSelector.bxSlider();
});
```